# Show that, for $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d) , \Vert f \Vert_{2}^2 = - \frac{1}{d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i\partial_{i} (|f|^2) \ dx$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

As the title states, I wish to establish the identity $\Vert f \Vert_{2}^2 = - \frac{1}{d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i\partial_{i} (|f|^2) \ dx$. I have attempted integrating by parts which gives me

$$\Vert f \Vert_{2}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f|^2 \ dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \partial_i (x_i) |f|^2 \ dx = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i \partial_i (|f|^2) \ dx,$$

which is not quite the identity I wish to establish as I am lacking the factor of $1/d$. Note that the boundary terms vanish since $f$ is Schwartz, and the subscript indicates the $i$th component and $i$th derivative. Where am I going wrong when integrating by parts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm reading things correctly, what you say you want and what you say you've done are the same except for a factor of $1/d$. Yes? Assuming so: It looks like what you've done is correct. I conjecture that there is simply a typo in what you say you want: Insert $\sum_{i=1}^d$ and you're set.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If i do add $\sum_{i}^d$, I then have $\sum_{i}^d \Vert f \Vert_2^2$ which is $d$ times the right side given in the above calculation. I thought I saw it, but I still do not...

Comment: Could there be some Einstein summation convention going on, where reapeated indices are summed? i.e., $a_i b_i$ means $\sum_i a_i b_i$

Comment: I don't get what you don't get. Suppose you've shown that $A=B_1$, $A=B_2$ and $A=B_3$. It follows by like arithmetic that $A=1/3\sum_{i=1}^3 B_i$.

Comment: OH. You're inserting the $\sum$ on the left side. My conjecture was that the $\sum$ should be inserted on the right side...

Comment: Right. That was where the confusion came from. Applying the sum to the right makes it obvious....finally. Thanks for the help.